# Can't get QSignalMapper to work

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making an application using the C++ Qt Framework. The problem I have at the moment is similar to submitting a form. I need to add a Client to the system. So when you click the "Add Client" button, it needs to submit the text from a QLineEdit and a QDate from a QDateEdit to a function.

The more I have researched, the more it seems I have to use a QSingalMapper, but I cannot seem to get it to work at all.

Here's a snippet of the code I tried to use first. I have a Client data structure with the Name and Joining Date that needs to be submitted. I can, however, also create the Client object and pass that through as a parameter insead if it's a better idea.

```
 QObject::connect(addClientBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addClient(clientName->text(), joiningDate->date())));
```

When I tried to use QSignalMapper, it kept telling me that I can't send a Client object because its not of type QString, Widget*, etc.

Is there maybe an easier way to do this that I've overlooked? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why do you bother with signal mapper in a case like this. Just connect your button's `clicked` signal to some slot where you either emit another signal, or just call the needed function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `QSignalMapper` if I understand you correctly but its difficult to tell as you hardly posted any code. Expecially it is difficult because we have no idea what `this` is. But assuming it is a `QDialog` or `QMainWindow`, you have to do something along the following:

**in the class definition *.h***

```
...
protected slots:
    void add_client();
...
```

**in the class implementation *.cpp***

```
mydialogormainwindow::mydialogormainwindow(){

    QObject::connect(addClientBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addClient()));
}

void mydialogormainwindow::add_client(){

    QString name = clientName->text();
    QDate date = joiningDate->date();
    ....
}
```

This is due to the signal-slot connection. The Signal sends out a signal including parameters which are sent to the slot. The clicked signal has no parameters so it can't send anything along to the slot. But with the slot being defined in the same class, you can access the data there directly.

**Note:** This works only if your class is a derived `QObject` (which is the case for `QDialog` and `QMainWindow`) and has the `Q_OBJECT` macro in its class definition.

Comment: Ah okay, this actually makes a lot of sense. "this" does refer to a QMainWindow, I wasn't too sure if I was able to access the clientName and joiningDate in the function itself, but I'm just being silly. Thanks a lot for clearing this up!